# removing a div on double click using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this on double click but I am having no luck what do i change the "click" to to make it double click because "dblclick" doesn't work in its place

```
$('.shapes').on("click", function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass("master"))
{
    $(this).remove();
}   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sU8mA/3/

Comment: I am not sure i tried it and it just doesn't want to remove it only works when i have click but i need it to be double click

Comment: give your HTML example in a Fiddle/JsBin so we can see what's going on. `dblclick` is the method, if it does not work out-of-the-box, you must have something blocking it, wither an element on top of it, or a javascript error

Comment: now added jsfiddle at the top

Comment: the shape on the side that gets cloned i want that to disappear on a double click the master i want to stay there

Answer (score 1):

`dblclick` - API: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/AyD3S/ `:)`

**code**

```
$('.shapes').on("dblclick", function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass("master"))
{
    $(this).remove();
}   
});
```

Comment: hmm it seems then that the if is intefering with it somehow then

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/85k3d/3/

```
//double clicking a master shape copy
    $('.master').on("dblclick", function() {
        //Remove old shape
         $('.shapes2').fadeOut();

        //Clone new shape
        var $clone = $(this).clone();
        $clone.attr("id", "shape"+counter);
        $clone.removeClass('master');
        $clone.addClass('shapes2');
        $clone.appendTo("#playArea");
        counter++;


    });
```

Comment: Take a look at my changes ;) Sry misunderstood your question.

Comment: one more try ;) This one should solve your problem and reduce code

Comment: Not working is not a helpfull comment. So you click on a shape on the right side and on double click a copy is diplayed in the #playArea container. If you double click another shape on the right side the previous one inside #playArea is getting removed and the new one gets inserted into #playArea. Thats exactly what you described as your wished feature and what my jsFiddle example does.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you could provide a link to your example. I assume this is the effect you are trying to recreate

http://jsfiddle.net/V5qY8/

You could try removing the class when it is double clicked instead of looking for the class via an if statement

### html

```
<div class="master">
    </div>``
```

### JQuery

```
$( ".master" ).dblclick(function() {
  $( this ).remove();
});
```

Comment: the only problem with that being is that masters also have a class of shapes aswell thats why i need to make sure it deletes the .shapes and not the .masters

Comment: you can can just change $('.master") to $(".shapes"). How you the sheet styled? Do you have <div class= "master shapes"> or is there any demo?

Comment: also i have added jsfiddle at the top so you can have a look at what is not working

Comment: again if i change .master to .shapes it also deletes .master because the .master elements also carry .shapes its only the cloned elements that do not have .master